# warnings when computing confidence intervals using confint for linear growth model fit with lme4 in R

Tags: r, lme4

I have fit a simple linear growth model using the `lme4` package in `R`. The model converges with no problem, but I get several warning messages when I try to compute the confidence intervals for the parameters using `confint`.

Here's the code for fitting the model and printing results:

```
model2.win <- lmer(fcz.win ~ age.12.0 + (1 + age.12.0|id),
                   data = ipandaLong,
                   REML = FALSE)
summary(model2.win)
confint(model2.win)
```

Output all looks fine for `summary()`:

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: fcz.win ~ age.12.0 + (1 + age.12.0 | id)
   Data: ipandaLong

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  5280.2   5308.0  -2634.1   5268.2      753 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.9098 -0.5105 -0.0405  0.4693  3.1713 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 id       (Intercept) 46.7861  6.8400        
          age.12.0     0.5386  0.7339   -0.16
 Residual             29.9463  5.4723        
Number of obs: 759, groups:  id, 315

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  13.9140     0.4714 279.0872  29.515  < 2e-16 ***
age.12.0      0.6989     0.1016 220.5225   6.881 6.08e-11 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr)
age.12.0 -0.354
```

But I get the following error message for `confint()`:

```
> confint(model2.win)
Computing profile confidence intervals ...
Warning in nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  unexpected decrease in profile: using minstep
Warning in nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  Last two rows have identical or NA .zeta values: using minstep
Warning in nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  Last two rows have identical or NA .zeta values: using minstep
.
.
.
Warning in nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  Last two rows have identical or NA .zeta values: using minstep
Warning in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : non-monotonic profile for .sig02
Warning in confint.thpr(pp, level = level, zeta = zeta) :
  bad spline fit for .sig02: falling back to linear interpolation
Warning in regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm) :
collapsing to unique 'x' values
                 2.5 %     97.5 %
.sig01       6.0312852  7.7166581
.sig02      -0.4192282  0.3146656
.sig03       0.2908488  1.0457268
.sigma       5.0355221  5.9563416
(Intercept) 12.9817107 14.8563276
age.12.0     0.4975101  0.9008158
```

I've tried switching to `method = bootstrap` and `method = Wald` but I run into bigger problems (NA values for Wald and Singular error message for bootstrap).

My questions are:

1. What does this error message mean
2. Can it be ignored
3. If not, how do I resolve the problem

Thanks!

Edit: Here is a plot of the profiles

[image: Plot]

Comment: Any chance we could have a reproducible example?  Warnings like this happen when the profile likelihood calculation starts getting wonky answers.  The easiest way to diagnose these problems is to construct the profile and plot it, e.g. see https://rpubs.com/bbolker/glmmchapter and search for "suspicious" ...

Comment: Thank you for sharing this link! Unfortunately I'm not sure how to reproduce this exact problem. I've added the summary output and confidence interval results if that is at all helpful.

Comment: "reproducible" means having your data (`ipandaLong`) available. Short of that, having you construct the graph shown in the link posted above and post it here would be the most useful thing you could provide.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification about the meaning of reproducible. Unfortunately I don't have permission to share the data. I've added the plot of the profiles to the original post (at the end - the edit section. Would you mind explaining how to interpret this figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This should probably be moved to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).)

Based on the profile plots, it looks like the profile confidence intervals — which are determined by the intersections of the profiles with the critical thresholds (shown as horizontal dashed lines in the figure you present) — are fine; that is, any weirdness/non-monotonicity in the profile curves, such as the kink in the `.sig02` profile (top row, middle), seems to occur outside of the central range we really care about. Otherwise the curves are reasonably smooth. (In this case *linear* profiles would mean we could get away with the simpler Wald approximations — this appears to be true for some but not all of the parameters.)

Comment: This explanation is very helpful, thank you!!